How to connect with walletConnect using Angular
I am working on dapp with angular project and I have task to apply walletConnect Service, so I used
@walletconnect/ethereum-provider which helped me to open socket and connect using wallet connect service
This is the code related to initalizing and connecting walletConnect service:
    this._web3Service.providerForWalletConnect = await EthereumProvider.init({
      projectId: environment.blockchain.walletConnectProjectId, // REQUIRED your projectId
      chains: [environment.blockchain.chainId], // REQUIRED chain ids
      showQrModal:true, // REQUIRED set to "true" to use @walletconnect/modal,
    });
    await this._web3Service.providerForWalletConnect.connect({
      chains: [environment.blockchain.chainId], // OPTIONAL chain ids
      rpcMap:environment.blockchain.rpcUrl, // OPTIONAL rpc urls
    });
    this._web3Service.providerForWalletConnect.sendAsync({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" }, (err, accounts) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(this._translateService.instant('checkout.some_thing_went_wrong'))
      }
      // console.log(res);
      if (accounts) {
        this._web3Service.handleConnectWalletSuccess(accounts.result[0])
        this._web3Service.isMetaMaskConnection = false
      }
    });

Every thing was working well, but suddenly i get this issue  when i am trying to open the popup which i initalize walletConnect inside it

I tried change @walletconnect/ethereum-provider by using @walletconnect/web3wallet or web3Model, but i didn't find any support for angular
